# What is SecDownloader

Tags: android

Developing an app for some months, I recently noticed a new entry in the log on my phone:

```
V/SecDownloader( 1203): HINT   : MyApplication.apk
V/SecDownloader( 1203): FILENAME: /mnt/sdcard/download/MyApplication.apk
```

What is `SecDownloader`, and what does it do with my `APK-file`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the logcat output is printing the process ID in the parenthesis, using "adb shell ps" to see the processes, so you can find out the name of the process associated with pid 1203.

That gives you the package name, you can find out more details about it with "adb shell dumpsys package ".